# Best solution for accessing images, css, js, etc

Tags: webserver

Apache uses too much memory, I want to set up a seperate server **(http://assets.domain.com)**

What webserver can I set up on Ubuntu server that can deliver fast content?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't see how this is a programming question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at nginx or lighttpd